# mod_python returns plaintext script?

Tags: 12.10, python, apache2, python-2.7

Ubuntu 12.10 Server in a virtualbox VM.

I have installed `mod_python` using `apt-get`,enabled it using `a2enmod`, and rebooted `apache2`.  I have also edited `\etc\apache2\sites-available\defaults` as below.  My script resides in `/var/www/py/` and is called via a jQquery.ajax post function.  This script is triggering, but returns itself - in plain text.  It should be returning json, indicating that I have missed some obvious setup step.

Uncommenting the testhandler line, below, results in the script returning mod_python.testhandler output - *essential* the php.info() output, but for python.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

         ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/py>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddHandler mod_python .py
                #PythonHandler mod_python.testhandler
                PythonDebug On
        </Directory>
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem here. What are you expecting?, it is a response header problem?, did you encode your response in json inside your python script?. Please add more detail. BTW, mod_python is deprecated you should try to use wsgi.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-answer to your question: mod_python is no longer the recommended way of deploying python applications. Turning your application into a proper wsgi app and using mod_wsgi is the state of the art.

Now for an actual answer: You'll need to set up a handler. mod_python doesn't just run random scripts, but you need to specify which module contains the handler, this is what AddHandler does.

For more info, see the [mod_python tutorial](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/tut-what-it-do.html).